# why log method's position doesn't matter in project reactor

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have below code, where `log()` method is invoked at two different places. but the resulting log output is same in both the case.

```
Mono mono1 = Mono.just("vashishth").log().map( s -> s.toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT));
mono1.subscribe(name -> log.info(name.toString()));

Mono mono2 = Mono.just("vashishth").map(s -> s.toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT)).log();
mono2.subscribe(name -> log.info(name.toString()));
```

`log()` methods documentation says *Observe all Reactive Streams signals*. what does it mean exactly, why log() methods invocation doesn't impact the logging output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says `Observe all Reactive Streams signals`.

So yes exactly what does that mean. To know that we need to know how a reactive chain works.

`log`is not what you expect, its not a `System.out.prinln` in that specific part of the chain. Where you place the `log` statement won't actually really matter.

So what is a `signal`. Well as soon as you use a `Mono` you are basically telling that `whenever i have a value in this mono please call the next operator in the chain` (in your case the next operator is `map`). So how do we know that we have a value in the `Mono`? well thats the thing. The mono will *signal* when there is a value.

On a high level you can sort of say that when a `Mono` gets its value, it will signal `next` and this will then tell `map`to call the `Mono` with a `onNext` call.

So the operators are sort of talking to each other
So the steps are for instance:

- Value lands in a mono
- Mono signals `next` and provides the value
- `map` then calls `onNext` to run its logic on the provided value from the `Mono`

This is what is called the *reactive chain* because each step is talking to the next step. And when you add a `log` statement, you get to see all this conversation between the different operators. And as the docs say, you get to see **all** the conversation, so it doesn't matter where you place it, you will always see all the conversation from the first operator, until the last.

When you declare something like

```
Mono.just("foobar").map(s -> s.toUppercase()).subscribe(System::out::println);
```

You dont declare the signaling. It happens "underneath the hood" without you knowing it. but you see it in the logs when you add `log` to the chain.

Comment: i may be making it look complex then it is. But in below code what is a stream and what's a signal?

Mono.just("vashishth").log().map( s -> s.toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT));

Comment: i updated my answer, you dont declare any signaling, it happens autmatically under the hood.